# File password protected

Tags: java, libreoffice

I have a conversion tool that converts `MS Doc files` to `PDF` using `LibreOffice Open Office`. If the `MS Doc` is password protected, it does the conversion and produces nonsense. I want to be able to detect the presence of a password on the source file. 
Can this be done with a `StreamReader` or a property before doing the conversion?

Basically

```
OfficeDocumentConverter converter = new OfficeDocumentConverter();
    if (!passwordOnSourceFile){
       convertedFile = new File("mynewfile.pdf");
       converter.convert(originalForConversion, convertedFile); 
    }else{
       //Cant convert
    }
```

Thanks,

Comment: What conversion tool are you using?

Comment: It's an in house tool written in Java using LibreOffice.

Comment: It seems that open office does not support all password protected office file. https://help.libreoffice.org/Common/About_Converting_Microsoft_Office_Documents#Opening_Microsoft_Office_Documents_That_Are_Protected_With_a_Password

Comment: That help page is outdated. All current OOXML encryption methods should be supported in current releases.